# Performance issues with windows.xaml that are using transparency - opacity

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, opacity

I just realized that some of my Window.xaml are opening with some kind of delay, opening is not instant as other `Window.xaml` (forms) which are NOT using transparency.

So I just figure out that it's probably about transparency or maybe I am wrong, whatever, this is how it looks right now when I open a window:

There is a small grid with white background in the center, and background of the window is transparent..

[image]

Here is my code (I did not provided code of textboxes with blue border that are behind opened window)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="TEST"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="TEST"
    Width="1024" Height="768" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" >

   <Window.Background>
         <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.4" />
    </Window.Background>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid Width="640" Height="440" Background="White">
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

So guys I realized that sometimes this even causes application not responding when I keep opening very fast this window with opacity, it looks like CPU can not render it as fast as I am opening it..
And I need to open it very often, and I'm afraid it might crush my application..

Is there any solution to this, because another window that I'm using in my app are opening really fast and working without problems..

Comment: It's probably the DropShadowEffect that is causing the delay.. Those effects are not very quick... Try commenting that part out and see if it is faster

Comment: @JordyvanEijk Nah, I tried without it also, and it's same.. :(